# Training for Pro-Soccer Tryouts

Tags: workout-routines, training, programs, running-training-plan, soccer

I'm in a 1-year long journey to hopefully prepare myself to try-out for a pro-soccer team. I was hoping to get some guidance from the community, as to training workouts that I can use to prepare.

Currently, I'm training using once/week :

**"suicide" runs (aka. lines in Basketball)**

1. 4x the length of the field (purpose: longer distance for endurance to running up/down field)
2. 3X the width of the field (purpose: shorter length at 100% sprint for short distance)
3. I rest in-between by juggling about 100x--then hit my next rep.

**Running**

1. Run for about 60mins

I also run about 60mins

The issue with all this is that I have no real milestone, times that I need to meet to simulate what the pro's are doing.

Does anyone know of any resources or know this type of information?

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is already really terrific. This regiment helps to build your endurance and lung capacity immensely. As a normal match for soccer is 90 minutes, what your doing should suffice, but something you can do is try and increase that 60 minute marker. If you can run for a solid 90 minutes and only be a little winded by the end, this will be invaluable on the pitch. To do this, you can slowly increase how long you run by say 5 minutes each week, but train twice a week with the same marker. The gradual intensity will give your body time to adjust and become stronger. While you are covering all the bases with endurance and running, you may want to approach the topics of leg strength and core strength. These are also key things that a soccer player needs to have. Certainly different training with a medicine ball will help with your core, as well as the standard core building exercises. Legs can be worked on through squats and other derivatives of that. Hopefully this helps and I wish you luck going forward on your journey! Hope to see you out on a pitch someday!

Answer (score 1):

I continued to try and do some more research for actual training plans and stumbled across the Stanford Soccer training program.

Here is a link to the full PDF: http://froeberg.com/soccerunited/stanfordfitness.pdf

Here is a snippet of the contents that I'll be using as my "Bible" for training:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion to build up endurance that I used to do on my soccer team was to use the perimeter of a field (not full length):

- jog 1 side, sprint 1
- jog 2, sprint 2
- jog 3, sprint 3, etc.
- jog 4, sprint 4

and then work your way back down. It helped to change speed instead of a blanket 'run for 60 minutes'.

Additionally, if you don't have a baseline you could always outline the workout you want to do, time yourself, and continue measuring that to see if the time for each exercise is improving.